# App xaml assumes the first window instantiated is the main window (showdialog is ignored), I need to show multiple windows

Tags: wpf, windows, app.xaml, mainwindow

I have the following code in my App.xaml.cs

```
private void App_Start(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
  if ( CompletedInstall())
  {
    //using show to allow for pacifier if loading is slow
    var manager = new WINServiceConfig();
    MainWindow = manager;
    manager.ShowDialog();
  }
}

private bool CompletedInstall()
{
    var window = new Initialize();
    window.ShowDialog();
    return window.DoLaunchManager;
}
```

and the following in the App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="Manager.App"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Startup="App_Start">
```

When i comment out the line that checks **CompletedInstall()** the **manager.ShowDialog()** works fine, and my configuration window shows.
When **CompletedInstall()** is called the call to **manager.ShowDialog()** returns right away without displaying the window.  I added the main window on the assumption that somewhere along the line someone decided an app should only show one window.

I found a workaround by setting the main window before calling CompletedInstall

```
        private void App_Start(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
          var manager = new WINServiceConfig();
          MainWindow = manager;

          if (CompletedInstall())
          {
            manager.ShowDialog();
          }
```

but this forces me to develop WINServiceConfig (specifically the constructor) based on its use, because it cannot count on the prerequisites being completed.  This is bad form.  What else can i do to get around this problem?

Dummy window?  That can't be the best answer.  Can it??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should set the ShutdownMode to OnExplicitShutdown (at least while showing the initial dialog).